# Drupal The requested page "/" could not be found

Tags: mysql, drupal

I am working for a client. I have migrated a drupal database into a new site and the installation went through without any issues but I am getting this message when loading the website "The requested page "/" could not be found.". Apart from this I have tried to log into the admin but I was unable to login. I thought of looking directly into the database as advised from other forums. But I cant find the "Users" table which is suppose to hold the user details. Can anyone please let me know if previous versions of drupal might have not include the "users" table? or is there a way to go about the "The requested page "/" could not be found." issue. Thank you.

I also found this https://drupal.org/node/142289 - but im not sure how to apply repair table in mysql. There might also possibly be other tables which may require repair and cant be found like the "Users" table.

Answer (score 0):

If your DB is missing tables or corrupt I think taking a new dump of the DB will be the easiest option.

Both D6 and D7 have a `users` table.